# Why use non-struct types in Golang?

Tags: go

I have been learning Golang for quite some time. I came across `type MyFloat float64`. Why is that not `var MyFloat float64` or
`type MyFloat struct{param float64}`? What is the purpose of having something like that?

In case you were wondering where I got that from, it is from the Golang tour [here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9) on line 27.

Comment: "Why is that not var MyFloat float64" Because its a type, not a variable.

Comment: In this particular case, they made the MyFloat type so that they could then write a method against it.  so it can be called myfloat.Abs(), instead of writing a basic function like Abs(myfloat) or Abs(float).